# Popup: inbox is blank

Tags: support, global-inbox, stack-exchange-button

My inbox in The StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ is blank. I am using Firefox 9.0. I'm sorry if this is caused by my browser.

Comment: I'm using FF 9 as well and it works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We are currently doing maintenance on our caching servers.  Things will return to normal once this is completed.

Comment: It works now. It seems fixed.

Comment: Mine's still broken... should it not be?